# How to add list items to a ListView in C#winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a list of objects. I want to add these items to a ListView. I'm trying to add each list item row wise but format is very bad, it should be in proper table type format.

```
        List<string> lst = new List<string>();
        lst.Add("John dsfsfsdfs " + "1" + 100);
        lst.Add("Smith sdfsdfsdfs" + "2" + 120);
        lst.Add("Cait dsffffffffffffffffffffff" + "3" +  97);
        lst.Add("Irene" + "4" + 100);
        lst.Add("Ben"     + "5" + 100);
        lst.Add("Deniel           jjhkh " +  "6" + 88);

        foreach(string pl in lst)
        {
            listView1.Items.Add(pl);

        }
```

Items are not visible and it should be in proper format.

[image: Table Format]

Comment: The `ListView` control can display items in several ways. For tabular view make sure you set the [View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.view.aspx) property to `Details`

Comment: i tried to set Details, but its was displaying blank listview

Comment: Have you set the [Columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.columns.aspx) property? “If your `ListView` control does not have any column headers specified and you set the View property to `Details`, the `ListView` control will not display any items.”

Comment: _not working_ is not a useful message!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To make it multicolumn:
1) set the ListView into Details mode:

```
    listView1.View = View.Details;
```

2)set up your three columns:

```
    listView1.Columns.Add("Column1Name");
    listView1.Columns.Add("Column2Name");
    listView1.Columns.Add("Column3Name");
```

3) add your items:

```
    listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[]{"John dsfsfsdfs ", "1" , "100"}));
```

4) To make it more viewable try:

```
listView1.GridLines = true;
```

5) To hide columns headers:

```
 listView1.HeaderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeaderStyle.None;
```

Comment: It's correct if you just want to add list of strings o one-column listView :) In your case you shuld avoid it. Just use everything below "To make it multicolumn" and it will be fine :)

Comment: is there any way to hide column name ??

Comment: And it really does not work. You were right. I'll correct my answer, sorry

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`ListViewItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/faw83h4f(v=vs.110).aspx) directly to create an item with subitems (-> "tabular") instead of just adding strings to your ListView:

```
listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem (new[]{"John dsfsfsdfs", "1", "100"}));
listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem (new[]{"Smith sdfsdfsdfs", "2", "120"}));
listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem (new[]{"Cait dsffffffffffffffffffffff", "3", "97"}));
listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem (new[]{"Irene", "4", "100"}));
listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem (new[]{"Ben", "5", "100"}));
listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem (new[]{"Deniel           jjhkh", "6", "88"}));
```

Comment: Thanks very much, exactly what I was looking for, straight and simple.

Answer (score 1):

can you create a DataTable and bind it as a source

```
foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
{
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(row[0].ToString());
    for (int i = 1; i < data.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        item.SubItems.Add(row[i].ToString());
    }
    listView_Services.Items.Add(item);
}
```