# JSON to ListView in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I wanna make app where i have list with my games on steam. I get Steam API Key and i get JSON with my games data but i don't know how i can get this to my ListView or something like this.

Im trying to find some tutorials and i find with Newtonsoft.JSON but i still get errors.

How JSON Looks:

```
{
   "response":{
      "game_count":27,
      "games":[
         {
            "appid":730,
            "name":"Counter-Strike: Global Offensive",
            "playtime_2weeks":986,
            "playtime_forever":30571,
            "img_icon_url":"69f7ebe2735c366c65c0b33dae00e12dc40edbe4",
            "img_logo_url":"d0595ff02f5c79fd19b06f4d6165c3fda2372820",
            "has_community_visible_stats":true,
            "playtime_windows_forever":1600,
            "playtime_mac_forever":0,
            "playtime_linux_forever":0
         },
         {
            "appid":224260,
            "name":"No More Room in Hell",
            "playtime_forever":0,
            "img_icon_url":"684de0d9c5749b5ddd52f120894fd97efd620b1d",
            "img_logo_url":"670e9aba35dc53a6eb2bc686d302d357a4939489",
            "has_community_visible_stats":true,
            "playtime_windows_forever":0,
            "playtime_mac_forever":0,
            "playtime_linux_forever":0
         },
         {
            "appid":232010,
            "name":"Euro Truck Simulator",
            "playtime_forever":11,
            "img_icon_url":"6b1bb4a4e2b1e0d85ad0b3e2d6d15a0258aa43a0",
            "img_logo_url":"fa3886315d9586671506c7149c1e4ecae653ce13",
            "has_community_visible_stats":true,
            "playtime_windows_forever":0,
            "playtime_mac_forever":0,
            "playtime_linux_forever":0
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I trying this but it's doesn't works.

```
json = wc.DownloadString("http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=D4718FA8ED43C531523CF79310BE52FE&steamid=76561198440001695&include_appinfo=1");
dynamic results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
var appid = results.appid();
```

i get error:

- $exception {"Component „Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject” doesn't contain a definition „appid”."} Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException

Comment: I think this might help you out sir. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39924376/how-to-bind-json-to-listview-control

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should deserialize this string with the generic deserializer method of Newtonsoft.

try making a new class:

```
 public partial class GameResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("response")]
    public Response Response { get; set; }
}

public partial class Response
{
    [JsonProperty("game_count")]
    public long GameCount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("games")]
    public Game[] Games { get; set; }
}

public partial class Game
{
    [JsonProperty("appid")]
    public long Appid { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("playtime_2weeks", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public long? Playtime2Weeks { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("playtime_forever")]
    public long PlaytimeForever { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("img_icon_url")]
    public string ImgIconUrl { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("img_logo_url")]
    public string ImgLogoUrl { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("has_community_visible_stats")]
    public bool HasCommunityVisibleStats { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("playtime_windows_forever")]
    public long PlaytimeWindowsForever { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("playtime_mac_forever")]
    public long PlaytimeMacForever { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("playtime_linux_forever")]
    public long PlaytimeLinuxForever { get; set; }
}
```

then use:

```
var json = wc.DownloadString("http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=D4718FA8ED43C531523CF79310BE52FE&steamid=76561198440001695&include_appinfo=1");
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GameResponse>(json);
```

Fiddle:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/Nf2LdB

Comment: that's works but how i can add this data to ex. ListView?

Comment: ListView in winforms ? maybe this could help:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43841962/how-to-add-list-items-to-a-listview-in-cwinform